# unable to set variable in OR condition when the first condition fails inside a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

These commands are inside a bat file which has delayed expansions enabled. I'm trying to check for a non existent command so that if it fails my programs doesn't hang up and I have a flag which can help me.

The flag here is `path_check`:

```
set /a path_check=1
echo !PATH! | ( findatr /i "C:\\Windows\\System32;" 2>NUL || echo "here")
```

this prints "here" with success:

```
set /a path_check=1
echo !PATH! | ( findatr /i "C:\\Windows\\System32;" 2>NUL || set /a path_check=1
)
echo !path_check!
```

this prints 1 instead of 0.

I can't attribute anything to this inconsistent behavior. In case the command exists but fails otherwise the program is responding fine.

**EDIT**

Based on the responses, I want to highlight that I'm using a non existent command and NOT a command that returns an error but exists otherwise. `findatr` is not a typo, it's intentionally that because I want to check for a non existent command.

Answer (score 1):

example (prints `0` if found, otherwise `1`):

```
set /a path_check=0
echo %PATH% | findstr /i "C:\\Windows\\System32;" 2>NUL || set /a path_check=1
echo %path_check%
```

Comment: yes, this is because findstr is recognized. Suppose I have a command which is not recognised like 'findatr' or whatever then this fails on my system.

Comment: you can also use `find /i "C:\Windows\System32;" 2>NUL`

Comment: I am understanding this because find and findstr are available commands. but suppose I have a command which is N/A which is different from it failing the output. like if I type `echo %PATH% | endoro this 2>nul || set /a path_check=0`now it doesnt work whereas I want it to set path_check=0 now.

Answer (score 1):

```
newcommand >nul 2>nul & if errorlevel 9009 echo command doesn't exist (on the path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but not at you expect!

The variable `path_check` is set to 1, but as the pipe creates a new cmd-context, the variable is only valid/accessible there.
And after the pipe is ready the sub cmd-context will be removed and also the variable.

But perhaps you should change your solution to first check if your program is in the path, before you try to start it.

```
set "path_check=0"
for /f "delims=" %%I in ("findatr.exe") do (
  if "%~$PATH:I" == "" set "path_check=1"
)
echo %path_check%
```